# ネットショップやホームページでアニメーションをつけたい

Tags: html, css

プログラミング初心者です。プログラミング学習でアニメーションをつける練習をしていてネットで落ち葉が降るアニメーションを見つけました。
サイトを参考にしつつVScodeでsampleというフォルダを作り同じディレクトリ内にindex.htmlとmain.jsと落ち葉の画像とcss/style.cssの計4種類のファイルを作りました。

こちらのindex.htmlでCSSとjsファイルを読み込み下記のCSSの任意のパスを記入というコード部分にbackground-image: url('/img/leaf-1.svg'); というコードを書いたところ無事落ち葉のアニメーションが降ってくるサイトを作れました。

しかしネットショップやwordpressで同じコードを記入してもCSSファイルとJSファイルのディレクトリが他の場所にあるのでうまく機能しません。
下記のコードを利用してネットショップやwordpressに落ち葉のアニメーションをつけることは可能なのでしょうか？
アニメーションのコードは以下のサイトを参考にしました。

https://web-dev.tech/front-end/javascript/autumn-leaves-falling-effect/

下記のコードがサイトに載っているCSSのコードです。

```
/* ===== 落ち葉を表示するコンテナのスタイル ===== */
.leaves-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh; /* コンテナの高さ */
  width: 100%; /* コンテナの横幅 */
  overflow: hidden; /* コンテナからはみ出した要素を隠す */
}

/* ===== 落ち葉のスタイル ===== */

/* 落ち葉の共通スタイル */
.leaf {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  position: absolute;
  animation: animate-leaf 8s linear;
}

/* 落ち葉1 */
.leaf-1 {
  background-image: url('img/leaf-1.svg'); /* 任意のパスを記入 */
}

/* 落ち葉2 */
.leaf-2 {
  background-image: url('img/leaf-2.svg'); /* 任意のパスを記入 */
}

/* 落ち葉3 */
.leaf-3 {
  background-image: url('img/leaf-3.svg'); /* 任意のパスを記入 */
}

/* ===== 落ち葉が降るアニメーション ===== */
@keyframes animate-leaf {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100vh;
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: ご自身で「CSSファイルとJSファイルのディレクトリが他の場所にあるのでうまく機能しません。」と書かれている通りパスが違ってCSSファイルとJSファイル(アニメーションファイルの置き場も別かもしれません)が読み込めていないためだと思いますが、どういうディレクトリ構成になっているかと、index.htmlファイルにどう読み込み部分を記述しているかも本文に記載していただいた方が的を射た回答が集まりやすいと思います。

Comment: 「うまく機能しません。」とは具体的には何が起きたのでしょうか？エラーが出ているならそれを追記してください。